# SwiftUI colorEffect shader alpha not respected in Dark Mode

Tags: swiftui, shader, metal

Xcode 15.0.1, iOS 17.0.2

**Problem**: when drawing a shader in Dark mode, a SwiftUI colorEffect shader does not respect the alpha channel of the given color.

This occurs in the Xcode Canvas (Preview), the Xcode simulator and on device.

Further... if I force-quit the app, set the device to Dark Mode, and relaunch the app, I very briefly see the desired result -- the globe shows on a dark background perhaps for 1 frame -- but then the globe is replaced by a solidly filled rectangle (the globe's frame).

This behaviour occurs regardless of whether the original or new color is a Dynamic Color or an absolute color (e.g. a hex value.)

```
// SwiftUI view

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "globe")
            .font(.system(size: 200))
            .foregroundStyle(.blue)
            .colorEffect(
                ShaderLibrary.replaceColor(.color(Color(hex: "ff8000")))
            )
    }
}

// Shader code

#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

[[stitchable]] half4 replaceColor(float2 pos, half4 oldColor, half4 newColor) {
    return half4(newColor.r, newColor.g, newColor.b, oldColor.a);
}
```

**Results in in Light Mode**

[image: Results in in Light Mode]

**Results in Dark Mode**

[image: Results after Dark mode is activated]

The documentation for the .color() shader utility states:

```
   /// Returns an argument value representing `color`. When passed
   /// to a MSL function it will convert to a `half4` value, as a
   /// **premultiplied** color in the target color space.
```

**Question**: what am I missing here? My guess is that it has something to do with the alpha premultiplication. But how to fix this?

Comment: Does this happen on simulator or device?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Sorry, I should have said. The problem occurs on the Canvas, Simulator and on device. (iPhone 12, running 17.0.2). Cheers.

Comment: And does it happen only on Dark Mode, or does it happen only if you toggle it after the view has been rendered? i.e. if you force-close the app, enable dark mode, and launch it, does it render correctly or not?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez If I force-quit the app, set the device to Dark Mode, and relaunch the app. I very briefly see the desired result -- the globe shows on a dark background perhaps for 1 frame -- but then the entire view becomes colorised.
I shall update my question with this info. Cheers.

Comment: It stays completely orange even after replacing `oldColor.a` with `0`. I don't think this has anything to do with pre-multiplication. Looks like a metal bug to me.